# Buying new RAM for GT780DXR

Tags: memory, compatibility

My [GT780DXR laptop](http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GT780DX-GT780DXR-.html#?div=Specification) is having memory problems, and I am looking to throw in a fresh 16GB. I am not much of a hardware guy. I hope superuser is the right place for this question.

This is what I have found so far:

```
Crucial Ballistix Sport
16 GB (2 x 8 GB)     # -
SO DIMM 204-pin      # SO-DIMM 204 is for laptops, as I understand it
DDR3                 # My current one is DDR3, so cannot be far off
1866 MHz / PC3-14900 # Faster than current RAM, so good
CL10                 # Lower the better, I believe
```

**My Question:** Is that kit compatible with a GT780DXR laptop?

Comment: Crucial, the company in question, has a compatibility program on their website to check what RAM is compatible with your computer.

Comment: I know, but it only shows a handful of compatible kits, the biggest of which is 8GB. I have used at least an hour on their website, without much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to say no.

Here is the official websage for your laptop:
http://www.msi.com/product/nb/GT780DX-GT780DXR-.html#?div=Specification

And it says DDR3 1066mhz and DDR3 1333mhz are the compatible speeds. 1866mhz would not work in it, unless there was an update to the BIOS that allowed it.

EDIT: As Unsigned mentioned, that ram should work but it would only run at 1333mhz since that is the rated speed the Mother Board will run it at.

Unless you want more ram it would be 
basically a waste of money since you won't get much increase in performance, if any at all.

EDIT2: Your laptops website says it has 4 memory slots, just as an FYI.

Comment: Unsigned is correct, I forgot about that.

Comment: Hm, I did have a look at the official website but I did not notice the the speeds. No reason to buy 1866MHz if it will only work at 1333MHz... Would `Crucial 16GB SO-DIMM 204-pin DDR3 1333MHz/PC3-10600 CL9 1.35V` be compatible?

Comment: Yes! Look here: http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/MSI+(Micro+Star)-memory/MSI+(Micro+Star)+Notebooks/GT780DX-215US-upgrades.html

That is crucial, they tell you on the left side what your laptop will take.

Answer (score 1):

The memory you posted is rated for 1.5v, but Corsair's recommended upgrade for your laptop is 1.35v. You would need to check your motherboard/BIOS to see if 1.5v is supported.

According to the documentation for your laptop, you need RAM that matches the following:

- DDR3
- SODIMM 204-pin
- 1066 or 1333MHz (faster than 1333MHz will work but won't perform any better)
- 1.35v